firebase hosting data transfer flutter web app
I'm looking into hosting a flutter web app for first time and I'm confused about that data transfer limit  in firebase, does data transfer here mean the amount of data used in serving of the web app to the user when they search and opens the web app , so for a web app of 5 mb (with 350mb/day limit on firebase data transfer ) does that mean only almost 70 users can access the web app a day? I'm confused about this part can someone please help me understand

According to the Firebase pricing page, on its free plan Firebase Hosting has a data transfer limit of 360 MB/day. If your compiled Flutter web app is 5Mb and each client downloads that complete web app, it indeed means that only ~70 new clients can access the web app per day.
If that is not enough for your use-case, you'll have to upgrade to Firebase's paid plan - which doesn't have a transfer limit.
